# Unknown relationship

Tags: database-design, referential-integrity

I have a problem with a database design:

I have an **EReport**. This **EReport** will have a **QAPCategory**. 
User must select a **QAPCategory** from an *set* of **QAPCategory**.

To know which **QAPCategory** can be selected I have done this design:

[image]

Is this correct? Is this a circular reference?

Comment: So an QAPCategory belonga to one EReport and an EReport has also a relation to one special QAPCategory?

Comment: What does the `FK1 | QAPCategory.eReportID` represent?

Comment: There is a list of `QAPCategory` that can be chosen from an `EReport` (`QAPCategory.eReportID`), and an `EReport` must have a `QAPCategory` (`EReport.qapCategoryId`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for both relationships.

Generally speaking, your category table should have one row per **category**, not per fact table row.

It's OK if multiple `EReport` rows refer to the same category record, but having a category record per `EReport` record defeats the purpose of normalizing in the first place.